# How to reorg online Oracle heavily used LOBs?

Tags: oracle, lob

We operate an Oracle 19c database.

Customer would like us to online reorganize some tables that has CLOBs fields stored in secure file.

There is no "low-load" time frame so the online reorgs fail with ORA-1555 every time.
... and in DBA_LOBS view the PCTVERSION, RETENTION fields are empty.

So the question is how could we increase the chance that online reorg finishes successfully?

Thankyou,
Darkvood

Comment: please share the DDL you are using for the reorg

Comment: hello, DDL is not relevant. In this case we cannot change tool that does it.
The question is how could we increase time frame before the receiving ORA-1555 from LOB.

Comment: If you are using a 3rd party tool and not your own DDL, you'll have to get support from folks who know that particular tool. We can't troubleshoot 3rd party code. To reorg a table you should just be using an `ALTER TABLE MOVE` command without any special tools. Can I ask what the purpose of the reorg is?

Comment: there is no purpose. Last decades customer get used to ask reorg of LARGE tables to free some space ... I know that it is optical tuning, but customer demands it so I have to make it possible.

Answer (score 1):

A reorg would only free up space if you have deletes opening up room in blocks that isn't getting reused, or have row chaining, or employ compression and some rows have gotten decompressed, or blew out the # of ITL slots with massive concurrent updates on rows in the same block (unlikely). For most tables there really no benefit to reorganizing the segment unless it is to implement a change (move to a new tablespace, compress, decrease PCTFREE, etc..). Normal delete and conventional insert uses space well enough, and what you squeeze out will soon return to its current state.

If the goal of freeing up space is *performance* (not space savings), then the only situation where this would help is if your queries are doing full table scans and one of the above scenarios has significantly enlarged the table over what it needs to be (or you have extensive row chaining). If your queries are using indexes it won't make a difference how large the table is.

If however you decide you really need to do a reorg, a simple segment reorg is done with the `ALTER TABLE MOVE` command:

`ALTER TABLE mytable MOVE`

This will move the table segment as well as any LOBs it has. By "*move*" I mean move it to new extents, to a new region of the tablespace. Doing this recreates the physical table and LOB segment(s) which is what accomplishes the physical reorganization at the block level. It doesn't have to involve moving it to a different tablespace (it can if you want).

Now the bare command above will be single threaded and therefore slow on a large table, will block your app from doing any DML on it while it's happening, and will leave your indexes unusable requiring manual index rebuilds afterwards. All of this is a problem for a large, busy table. So in your situation we need to add some additional options. You can make faster with parallelism (and `NOLOGGING`, if that's acceptable, which it usually is not in a production database). You can have it automatically rebuild indexes for you with `UPDATE INDEXES` and you can also do it while DMLs are happening with the `ONLINE` option, which sounds like in your case you may need it):

`ALTER TABLE mytable MOVE PARALLEL (DEGREE 8) ONLINE UPDATE INDEXES`

If you employ parallelism like this you may be able to get the work done fast enough to avoid that ORA-1555. If you have lots of CPU cores available, increase the parallelism to whatever you can get away with. 16, 32, 64, whatever, just leave enough CPU for your other workloads to not be impacted.

Comment: due to table size even the move runs for almost a day. This is more than enough time to get ORA-1555 caused by LOBs.

Comment: @darvud Exactly how large is the table? I've never seen a table so large it would take a day to move it. What degree of parallelism did you request, and did you verify that it obtained that many PX slaves and that they were carrying their share of the work? Did you see what wait event occupied most of their time, ensuring that it wasn't a concurrency issue? Did you check to see if it was getting work done the entire time, or if it was single threaded for hours waiting on obtaining an exclusive lock to do the dictionary switch (online still requires a brief exclusive lock at the end)?

Comment: after 13 hours of run, DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE cancelled with message: 
ORA-12008: error in materialized view or zonemap refresh path.
  ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 162 with name "_SYSSMU162_3614007614$" too small

Comment: @darvud - Why are you using `dbms_redefinition`? That isn't the correct method if all you wish to do is clean up space allocation. That's meant for making logical structure changes. You should instead be using the move DDL I suggested above. `dbms_redefinition` should have no part in this.

Answer (score 1):

meanwhile I found the answer.

Oracle automatically tunes undo retention time if there is free space in undo tablespace so UNDO_RETENTION parameter is technically obsolete and should not be modified.

But ... this is not valid for LOBs. In case of concurrent DML queries:

> A DML query shorter than "UNDO_RETENTION Seconds" does not fail with
> ORA-1551 Snapshots too old even though the DML modifies the LOB.
> Queries that last longer than "UNDO_RETENTION Seconds" may fail.
>
> If your want a different behavior, you need to increase the "N
> seconds".

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/adlob/automatic-securefiles-shrink1.html#GUID-9294F4FB-FFB4-4586-8376-BFB145EEDC40

So the solution is to increase UNDO_RETENTION from default 900 secs to a BIG value and make sure that there is enough space.

Regards,

Darvud.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using DBMS_REDEFINITION? In any event, the first phase of a online reorg is a 'snapshot' of the current data, which provides a base from which we can later apply deltas to keep the process up to date whilst still being online.

So in effect you'd need an undo retention (and similarly sized undo tablespace) for as long as it would take to do a "create-table-as-select" on your table.

You can experiment with a copy using subset of the data and extrapolate from there - it should be reasonably linear.

Also worth exploring some of the caching/logging options for your LOB to see if tweaking those improves the performance of the CTAS.

Comment: the problem is that LOBs use versioning instead of undo tablespace.